# Conflict with use of rel attribute in mootools

Tags: dom, mootools, rel

Looking for some insight into this problem.

I have dynamically generated links on a page that launch a lightbox ie they use a rel="lightbox[...]" I'm also putting a class on the hyperlink to make a tooltip work.

```
<a id="a_-1_6" class="Tips2" href="/media/63/forest_150.jpg" rel="lightbox[examples]" data-title="Tractor" data-desc="description..." data-rel="std" title="" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
```

And in the dom ready event

```
                var Tips2 = new Tips($$('.Tips2'), {
                initialize: function() { this.tip.fade('hide'); },
                onShow: function(tip) { tip.fade('in');  },
                onHide: function(tip) { tip.fade('out'); }
            });
```

This all works fine except the tip uses the rel attribute to store data, i'm presuming as its a pre-html5 - so my question is would this mean I need to make my own version of the Tips class in mootools to work off the data.* attributes? I'd like to see I'm not barking up the wrong tree before I try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tips](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Interface/Tips)' documentation states that you can change which property is checked for the tip text. By default, it is `rel` or `href`, but you can change it when initializing the new Tip:

```
var Tips2 = new Tips($$('.Tips2'), {
    initialize: function() { this.tip.fade('hide'); },
    onShow: function(tip) { tip.fade('in');  },
    onHide: function(tip) { tip.fade('out'); },
    text: 'data-text'        // Will now check the data-text property for tooltip text
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you make another element inside the Ahref, like:

```
<a id="a_-1_6" href="/media/63/forest_150.jpg" rel="lightbox[examples]" data-title="Tractor" data-desc="description..." data-rel="std" title="" style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
    <span class="Tips2">blah</span>
</a>
```

This way, you can avoid the conflict.